# Why my gcm only authorising my device registration id for the same app?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I trying to send the gcm push message through a java code by making json array and sending as a http ..

I have the array of registration ids for different devices same app. 
Problem:
The problem is whenever i send the gcm message to the array of registration ids , i get the success message only for the same registration id(device) from which i send the message and for other is shows invalid registeration id error in my return message from gcm.

App is only authenticating my own registration id ! why?
Please try to provide me some info. is that api key??

Comment: From where you got other reg ids????

Comment: other registration ids i am syncing from the server database to local database of android !! these registration ids i have generated using same application while logging

Comment: I also think it is getting correct format of registration ids.. as the device is sending messages to the same device registration id only.. If the registration ids are not correct it should not send to same device but it is sending to itself for all  devices i have checked that. :(

Comment: Only one id can be valid for a single device. So there is no error in your code. If you want more reg ids then create more emulators using Google API and then register those..

Comment: i have two devices and i have registered them for both, in the database i have two different registeration ids now, But the app only sends message to the registration id associated with its own

Comment: How do you send the message? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

private void sendPush(ArrayList registrationids,String message) throws Exception {

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

```
httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "key="key");
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

JSONObject topObject=new JSONObject();


JSONObject dataObject=new JSONObject();
dataObject.put("msg", message);
dataObject.put("title", "Test Title");

topObject.put("data", dataObject);

JSONArray arObject=new JSONArray();



for(int i=0;i<registrationids.size();i++)
{
arObject.put(registrationids.get(i));
Log.e("", registrationids.get(i)+"");
}

//arObject.put(registrationids.get(1));


topObject.put("registration_ids", arObject);

String jsonBody=topObject.toString();
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonBody,"UTF-8"));





HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

// Get the HTTP Status Code
int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

// Get the contents of the response
InputStream input = resEntity.getContent();
String responseBody = Utils.convertStreamToString(input);
input.close();

// Print the response code and message body
Log.e("HTTP Status Code:", statusCode+"");
Log.e("responseBody", responseBody);
```

}